# get every other value of string array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I am trying to populate a combo box with every other element of an array

the array contains data like this

```
(0) server
(0) sqlInstance
(1) server
(1) sqlInstance
(2) server
(2) sqlInstance
```

I want all sqlInstance values to be added to the combo box. Not sure how to do it other than maybe another array.

Thanks

```
Private Sub GetSQLServers()

        Dim oSQLApp As New SQLDMO.Application
        Dim oServerNames As SQLDMO.NameList
        Dim strServer As String
        Dim ServerArr() As String

        oServerNames = oSQLApp.ListAvailableSQLServers()

        For i = 0 To oServerNames.Count

            strServer = (oServerNames(i))
            ServerArr = strServer.Split("\")

            txtSQLHost.Text = ServerArr(0)

            For Each s As String In ServerArr
                'value of server instance
                cbxSQLServerNames.Items.Add(s)
            Next

        Next i
    End Sub
```

This is working, I'm pretty sure it is not the best way

The combo box fills with sqlInstances only
The txtbox has the server

oServerNames is server\sqlInstance

```
Private Sub GetSQLServers()

        Dim oSQLApp As New SQLDMO.Application
        Dim oServerNames As SQLDMO.NameList
        Dim strServer As String
        Dim ServerArr() As String
        Dim sn As Integer = 1

        oServerNames = oSQLApp.ListAvailableSQLServers()

        For i = 0 To oServerNames.Count

            strServer = (oServerNames(i))
            ServerArr = strServer.Split("\")

            txtSQLHost.Text = ServerArr(0)

            For Each s As String In ServerArr

                'value of server instance
                If ((sn Mod 2) = 0) Then
                    cbxSQLServerNames.Items.Add(s)
                    sn = sn + 1
                Else
                    sn = sn + 1
                End If
            Next
        Next i
    End Sub
```

Using this now..
Thanks

```
Private Sub GetSQLServers()

        Dim oSQLApp As New SQLDMO.Application
        Dim oServerNames As SQLDMO.NameList
        Dim strServer As String
        Dim ServerArr() As String

        oServerNames = oSQLApp.ListAvailableSQLServers()

        For i = 0 To oServerNames.Count

            strServer = (oServerNames(i))
            ServerArr = strServer.Split("\")

            txtSQLHost.Text = ServerArr(0)

           For Each item In oServerNames
                Dim parts = item.Split("\")
                Dim instance = parts(1)
                cbxSQLServerNames.Items.Add(instance)
            Next

        Next i
    End Sub
```

Comment: Use a List(Of Class) instead of an array then you can post whichever elements you want whereever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Try this:</s>

```
    For i = 0 To oServerNames.Count - 1 Step 2
        Dim serverInstance = oServerNames(i) & "\" & oServerNames(i + 1)
        cbxSQLServerNames.Items.Add(serverInstance)
    Next i
```

The `Count - 1` because, if you are count 10 items, you are counting from 0 to 9.

After looking at the source of your question, you say the array looks likes this:

```
(0) server
(0) sqlInstance
(1) server
(1) sqlInstance
(2) server
(2) sqlInstance
```

This is not possible. There can not be multiple items with the same index. Something is missing here...

---

If the array look like this:

```
(0) server\sqlInstance
(1) server\sqlInstance
(2) server\sqlInstance
```

You can do that:

```
For Each item In oServerNames
    Dim parts = item.Split("\")
    dim instance = parts(1)
    cbxSQLServerNames.Items.Add(instance)
Next
```

Comment: This returns server\sqlInstance\server\sqlInstance\server\sqlInstance

Comment: It should not return anything, but add multiple "server\sqlInstance" to a the ComboBox. Did I misunderstood something? - Yes after reading your question many times, I don't think I understood the contents of the array. Can you explain more cleanly, what the array exactly contains?

Comment: The array input is server\sqlInstance. After split("\") it is (0)server(0)Instance

Comment: @dummy is right, your question as it is is confusing. What exactly is 0? It can't be an array index here...

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using that statement corrected where serverInstance is Instance.

Comment: Ah, yes. That's whats happens if I don't run the code :). I wil correct the answer.

Comment: I did not express the array correctly. You got it though